# Issue while running a java application in Linux env

Tags: java, xml, linux, unix

I have a java project built in eclipse in my Windows machine. Now i had to run it in Linux machine. I created a jar , and i am trying to run the jar.

The main class, takes a XML file as input. Previously on Windows, i had given path of the file in Windows. Now i kept the .xml file in the root location in Unix.

can i modify the code in Windows, to the root path of Linux machine and try to run the jar.

I did it like this ,

```
XYZ parsero = new XYZ("//root//workflow.xml");
```

Created the jar and tried to run in Unix.

I got the below exception.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: root
```

How do i need to run this.

Comment: I got the solution.

It should be 

    XYZ parsero = new XYZ("/root/workflow.xml"); 

unlike in Windows.

Comment: as you found the solution, post it as an answer and mark as accepted

Comment: The reason why you use ``\\`` on Windows is because ``\`` is the escape character in strings. You can write `\t` to mean tab, `\n` to mean line feed, and ``\\`` to get a literal backslash. `/` is not an escape character and already literal, so you don't write two any more than you write `"hheelloo  wwoorrlldd"`.

Comment: @ fmodos I did not have the permission to do that till 8hrs. So i commented. I will put it. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. It should be XYZ parsero = new XYZ("/root/workflow.xml"); unlike in Windows